# Communication from client to server in Java

Tags: java, servlets, listener

### The system

For a school project, we need to build a system consisting of:

1. Two Raspberry Pi (communicating via Ethernet locally, a client and a server)
2. The server Pi (Tomcat is imposed) must generate a web page that evolves according to the inputs of a controller that is connected to the Pi client.
3. The implementation is done using Java and Java EE.

Here is the system at high level:
[The system needed (high level)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXLPp.png)

### The problem

The problem me and my colleagues are facing is that we want the *server* to update the web page when the *client* changes (i.e a button on the controller is pressed). Usually, it seems, the communication is in the other way, that is, from server to client.

*Is there any way to do this in Java?*

Notes:

- The web browser and the client are not on the same machine necessarily.

Comment: Your question covers a very big topic. I assume you are searching for a minimal example that implements such a communication. You may just search for such examples or tutorials. I suggest you try them and come back if you have a more specific problem :) For example a specific point where you have problems with your code.

Comment: I'm not looking for an example, but rather a pointer on which class or technology to use. We are new to Java and networking and we are a bit at loss. We are currently trying to connect a server socket that links the Pi client to the Pi server and forwards all messages received to Tomcat.

@redFIVE: this is part of my research.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. Web technology is request-response driven. The *client* makes a request (user clicks a button on page and web browser imitates a request sent to server), and the server responds. The opposite, client being updated based on something happening server-side, is known as [Push technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), and is new and bleeding-edge in the Web world. You are currently attempting to re-invent HTTP and the Web; that's already been done and it's working pretty well. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Servlets, especially google **HttpServlet** for sample code so that you can create a boilerplate code. You are going to design a web page with UI interactions, as you said, with a button click, let say, main part under the top navigation bar is going to be generated. Go minimal, after client connected and clicks a button, your server is going to render the page.

You can start by playing with the **doGet/doPost** methods of the `HttpServlet` class, here is a simple example;

```
package com.example.Main;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/mainpage")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String outputHtml = "<html><body><h3>Hello World !</h3></body></html>";

        resp.getWriter().write(outputHtml);
    }

}
```

This is only an HttpServlet hello world. Easy to see that you can modify the outputHTML so you need to write additional classes to do the rendering and generating the outputs.

A use of a class which takes parameters due to the user interactions and generate an HTML output will be fine (May be you can use a **Builder Pattern** for that).